# Apache Spark - How to zip multiple RDDs

Tags: scala, distributed-computing, apache-spark

Let's say I have a bunch of RDD's, maybe `RDD[Int]`, and I have a function that defines an operation on a sequence of ints and returns an int, like a fold: `f: Seq[Int] => Int`.

If I have a sequence of RDD's, `Seq[RDD[Int]]`, how do I apply the function and return a single new RDD with the resulting value? I don't seem to find a `zipPartitions` method in Spark which accomplishes this.

Comment: Would something like `rdd1.fold(0, f) ++ rdd2.fold(0, f)` work?

Comment: No not really, RDDs work a bit different, I need to get the Partitions and use `f` on them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At some point the elements of the `Seq[Int]` need to be bound to the parameters of `f`.  Whether this occurs beforehand by creating a collection ("materializing the lists") or by binding them one-by-one in a [partial function application](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_application) manner, at some point there needs to be a collection-like data structure that contains all of the elements.  Certainly, once inside `f`, they all need to be in the same place.

Here is a slightly more functional style implementation of Spiro's makeZip function:

```
def makeZip(xs: ListBuffer[RDD[Double]]): RDD[ListBuffer[Double]] = {
  // initialize with arrays of length 1
  val init = xs(0).map { ListBuffer(_) } 
  // fold in remaining by appending to mutable list
  xs.drop(1).foldLeft(init) { 
    (rddS, rddXi) => rddS.zip(rddXi).map(sx => sx._1 += sx._2)
  }
}
```

Comment: Long time since I posted this question :) But as you say, the lists must be materialized. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

A simplified example using zip instead of zipPartitions. (I don't see where your problem description actually *requires* zipPartitions.) The tricky part is the way zip wants to return an RDD of pairs when what you need is an RDD of lists.

```
// set up an example
val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(Array(1,2,3,4), 2)
val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(Array(11,12,13,14), 2)
val rdd3 = sc.parallelize(Array(21,22,23,24), 2)
val rdd4 = sc.parallelize(Array(31,32,33,34), 2)
val allRDDs = Seq(rdd1, rdd2, rdd3, rdd4)

// zip the RDDs into an RDD of Seq[Int]
def makeZip(s: Seq[RDD[Int]]): RDD[Seq[Int]] = {
  if (s.length == 1) 
    s.head.map(e => Seq(e)) 
  else {
    val others = makeZip(s.tail)
    val all = s.head.zip(others)
    all.map(elem => Seq(elem._1) ++ elem._2)
  }
}

// zip and apply arbitrary function from Seq[Int] to Int
def applyFuncToZip(s: Seq[RDD[Int]], f:Seq[Int] => Int): RDD[Int] = {
  val z = makeZip(s)
  z.map(f)
}

val res = applyFuncToZip(allRDDs, (s: Seq[Int]) => s.sum)
res.foreach(s => println(s))
```

If you really wanted to avoid materializing the lists, and instead wanted to apply the function incrementally, the solution would be more complicated.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I don't want to materializing the lists though.